# Access to session when making ajax call to Asp.net MVC action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i have a controller action being called using an ajax request, but when i tried to access session (HttpContext.Session["key"]), i dont have any of my session keys populated. How can i have access to my session keys when i make a call using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

The available Session in the controller is the HttpSessionStateBase. You can access it using either `Session[param]` or `base.Session[param]` if your controller inherits from Controller. But this may be useless with Ajax if you have it set cookieless.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to figure out why your session is not getting populated for Ajax calls.  I can only tell you that your session *should* get populated for Ajax calls.