# HttpRuntime.Cache collection is empty when action is invoked by Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out why my `HttpRuntime.Cache` collection is always empty when controller action is invoked by `$.ajax`? In actions invoked normally everything works perfectly and I can get my data from `Cache`. Maybe actions invoked by AJAX have some different lifecycle and `Cache` collection is not ready yet? This is my example code:

action:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult SomeAjaxAction()
{
   // when receive ajax request HttpRuntime.Cache is always empty, but it shouldn't be
   SomeType item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("cache_key") as SomeType;

   return PartialView("SomeAjaxActionView", item); 
}
```

invocation:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/controller/SomeAjaxAction/',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

Is there any way to fix it e.g by custom action filter?

**ANSWER**

Ok, I found answer here: [Access to session when making ajax call to Asp.net MVC action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897293/access-to-session-when-making-ajax-call-to-asp-net-mvc-action) So I imporoved my code with `base.HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("key")` and it works as expected!

Comment: please post your answer separately and then accept as answer.Then this will not come as a unanswered question for search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found answer here: [Access to session when making ajax call to Asp.net MVC action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897293/access-to-session-when-making-ajax-call-to-asp-net-mvc-action) So I imporoved my code with `base.HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("key")` and it works as expected!